# remove() not working for Newly created tag by append(). Can anyone help pls?

Tags: jquery

Why this .remove() not working for Newly created tag by .append().
eg: http://jsfiddle.net/id10922606/d0ms9uw5/3/

```
$(".photo").click(function(){  

//var x = $(this)[0].getAttribute('src');
var x =    $(this).attr('src');
//alert(x);

$(this).parent().append("<div class='zoom'><img class='zoomimg' src=''  /></div>");    
$('.zoomimg').attr('src', x);

});

$(".zoom").click(function(){
    //alert("Removing");
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: you need to look within an element already on the DOM at instantiation time. try `$(this).parent().find('.zoom').click(...` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delegate the event http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/
http://jsfiddle.net/d0ms9uw5/4/

```
$(".photo").click(function(){  

//var x = $(this)[0].getAttribute('src');
var x =    $(this).attr('src');
//alert(x);

$(this).parent().append("<div class='zoom'><img class='zoomimg' src=''  /></div>");    
$('.zoomimg').attr('src', x);

});

$(document).on('click', ".zoom", function(){ //<--See here
    //alert("Removing");
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".zoom").on('click', function(){
   $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: This wouldn't help, as this is actually not a proper event delegation. You need to delegate it to parent, not the element itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use event delegation for attaching events to newly/dynamically added elements:

```
$("body").on('click','.zoom',function(){
    //alert("Removing");
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: how to add fadeout effect after remove that element?

Comment: by using: `$(this).fadeOut(300, function(){ $(this).remove();});`